# LinkedIn connection type for someone you've interviewed

Tags: interviewing, linkedin, networking

I recently interviewed someone, and was suitably impressed. I want to connect on LinkedIn (the interview process is not complete yet), but am stumped by 'How do you know' connect options:

> [image]

Is he my friend? Is he my (to-be) colleague (what if he doesn't get the job)? Have we done business together?

## (Answers to) FAQs

1. No, we do not share a common group.
2. I don't know his email address (or rather which one he uses on LinkedIn), so can't use the *Other* option.
3. This is a rolling opening, so there aren't (technically) other candidates. Plus, adding him on LinkenIn (because being done for the right reasons *after* having spoken to him) is exactly the signal I want to give, if someone were receiving signals.

Comment: I suggest that you let the interview process with this individual play itself out before you try to connect with them on Linkedin. Keep in mind that you represent the company. If you try to connect with this individual now, you will give that individual the impression that they just about landed the offer, to the detriment of the other candidates. You will be the undermining the integrity of the company's hiring process by creating a perception of favoritism.

Comment: Is this question on topic here? Why don't you ask linked in what to put in the blank here? Or "Colleague" or "Other" or "Include a personal note" all seem appropriate!? ps. I think ppl taking LinkedIn a little too seriously! Stay in touch is fine and professional but keep it simple

Comment: why didn't you consider "Other" option - it's shown at your screen shot?

Comment: @gnat Because that requires me to provide the users email address, and I am note sure which one he might be using on LinkedIn, his current official ID or his personal ID.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to add LinkedIn contacts, not navigating the workplace.

Comment: Job seeking is an important part of the workplace, and LinkedIn etiquette is a critical part of that. This isn't about "how to click" it's about what's proper or rude.

Comment: @KatieK Is that addressed to me? I am not sure I understand the context.

Comment: @fgnu - The above is a response to the comment saying that the question is off-topic.

Comment: @KatieK Ah, you want to tag that person in that case. Gave me quite a shock. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An interview is business - so just choose "We have done business together" and specify your job. Pick the name of the company you are employed at that the interviewee was interviewing for.

Be sure to customize the text that LinkedIn will send to the other person. Just don't write a recommendation quite yet.

Answer (score 1):

> Is he my friend? Is he my (to-be) colleague (what if he doesn't get
>   the job)? Have we done business together?

In general, the only correct connection at the moment is most likely "other". Anything else would be presumptuous at worst, and awkward at best.

Better would be to wait until *after* this person is hired.

Comment: we can't tell if this is indeed the only correct connection, since there is an alternative that both share some group (we don't know since asker didn't clarify this). If the shared group matches their professional interests, it may be even better option than Other

Comment: @gnat, no we do not share a common group. Will update the question.